# "ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib" when installing face_recognition

Tags: python, pip, face-recognition

I'm facing this error while installing face_recognition in a virtualenv with Python 3.8.10 on Ubuntu 20.04.

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for face-recognition-models
  Running setup.py clean for face-recognition-models
Failed to build dlib face-recognition-models
Installing collected packages: Click, numpy, dlib, face-recognition-models, face-recognition
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: '/home/badrelden/Desktop/test python sound/venv/bin/python3' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tai2snq9/dlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tai2snq9/dlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-bhy0sde6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers '/home/badrelden/Desktop/test python sound/venv/include/site/python3.8/dlib'
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-tai2snq9/dlib/
    Complete output (8 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'tools/python/dlib/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    
    ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib
    
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: '/home/badrelden/Desktop/test python sound/venv/bin/python3' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tai2snq9/dlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tai2snq9/dlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-bhy0sde6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers '/home/badrelden/Desktop/test python sound/venv/include/site/python3.8/dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib
```

This is the key part of the error message. You need to install cmake, which can be done by running `sudo apt install cmake` on Debian-based systems, including Ubuntu. After cmake is installed, you can rerun the `pip install` command.

Comment: Thanks so much its worked fine with me